# Setting value of slider works in jsFiddle, not on live site

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, events, model-view-controller, jquery-ui-slider

I created a jQuery range slider that could slide on mouse pointer as well as on input from textbox. I created it on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MD3mX/1673/) and it works fine.

The problem is when I added the same code in my MVC application the slider doesn't slide on input change event. What could be the reason? Any version issue?

This piece of code doesn't move the slider on input change event:

**Jquery**

```
$("#MinimumPrice, #MaximumPrice").change(function () {
    var valueN = $("#MinimumPrice").val();
    var valuleX = $("#MaximumPrice").val();
    $("#slider-range").slider('values', [ valueN, valuleX ]);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="Price" class="main_filter" name="filterDiv">
<h4>Price</h4>
<div id="slider-range"></div>
<span class="">
    <br />
    <h4>Price Range</h4>
    <br />
    <div style="border: 1px solid #ccc;border-radius: 4px;width:100%;text-align: center;">
        <div class="input-group" style="width: 40%;float: left;">
            <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
            <input id="MinimumPrice" maxlength="6" name="MinimumPrice" style="border:0;width: 50%" type="text" value="" />
        </div>
        <span style="width: 20%;float: left;">to</span>
        <div class="input-group" style="width: 40%">
            <input id="MaximumPrice" maxlength="6" name="MaximumPrice" style="border:0;width: 50%" type="text" value="" />
        </div>
    </div>
</span>
```

Here is the [jsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/MD3mX/1673/).

Comment: Check the console for errors. As the fiddle works fine, there's nothing for anyone here to diagnose to help you with

Comment: Check if you have included all JS files in your page, layout or BundleConfig.

Comment: No errors in Console :(

Comment: Check the same in a Empty project it will work, if not then may be some conflicts in the `jquery` or any `Js` file.

Comment: Also try by putting the Related `.Js` in your Page.

Answer (score 0):

Just checked in the MVC project in it's working by doing this small change.

You had done In your example like this which is incorrect: `<div id="slider-range"></div>`

So this line: `$("#slider-range").slider('values', [ valueN, valuleX ]);` will not affecting in the code.

It should be like this: Change the end of `</div>` **slider-range** to end.

```
<div id="Price" class="main_filter" name="filterDiv">
    <h4>Price</h4>
    <div id="slider-range"> 
        <br />
        <h4 style="color:black">Price Range</h4>
        <br />
        <div style="border: 1px solid #ccc;border-radius: 4px;width:100%;text-align: center;">
            <div class="input-group" style="width: 40%;float: left;">
                <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                <input id="MinimumPrice" maxlength="6" name="MinimumPrice" style="border:0;width: 50%" type="text" value="" />
            </div>
            <span style="width: 20%;float: left;">to</span>
            <div class="input-group" style="width: 40%">
                <input id="MaximumPrice" maxlength="6" name="MaximumPrice" style="border:0;width: 50%" type="text" value="" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also check the same in the [jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/smit_patel/Ls4cpqmu/5/)

Comment: So there's may be some `Js` issue, because i am using the same in MVC application and it's working.